# command prompt conversion of TC to TE

Tags: testcomplete

I want to convert a project built in TestComplete to TestExecute using a .bat command

Due to the project being part of CI process new versions are released daily and conversion needs to occur automatically ;

.bat file for running project :

```
net use O: /delete
net use O: %1 /persisten:no

echo %PATH%

IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestExecute 12" (
    **I would like to enter conversion of project here**
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestExecute 12\Bin\TestExecute.exe" "O:\Diamond.pjs"
) ELSE (
    echo "test execute 12 not installed" 
)

net use O: /delete
```

Comment: TestComplete projects do not require a conversion to be run with TestExecute. What exactly your conversion does?

Comment: The version of the TC is older than the version of TE . thus conversion is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force conversion at the same time when running the project:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestExecute 12\Bin\TestExecute.exe" "O:\Diamond.pjs" /SilentMode /ForceConversion
```

Comment: As I understand it for the documentation of smartBear , there is no option to /ForceConversion not working with /SilentMode ?

Comment: If you open a project created in an old format without /SilentMode, you will see a dialog suggesting to convert the project. If you use /SilentMode without /ForceConversion, TestComplete won't convert your projects because the default button in this dialog is No. You need to use /ForceConversion to make TestComplete say Yes in this dialog when the /SilentMode parameter is used. So, why do you need to use /ForceConversion without /SilentMode? I do not see how this can be useful.

Comment: The project is created for the use of users other than me  , conversion should be forced while executing a run should be determined by the user .
As i understand there is no solution to this , 
thanks for all the clear explanations